# How to get img alt text and data-src using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML snippet :

```
<span class="photo_tooltip" id="__w2_YFXobXt_link">
<a href="/profile/Smit-Soni-2" id="__w2_GDetCwt_link">
<img class="profile_photo_img" src="https://assets.ec.quoracdn.net/-images.placeholder_img.png96cbdb37c749e493.png" height="50" width="50" data-src="https://assets.ec.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-18048885-50-ujrumofdevpkaarfisuvjdtbihztxnta.jpeg" alt="Smit Soni" />
</a></span>
```

I want to extract all the `alt` text and `data-src` from the `img class="profile_photo_img`. My code:

```
ele = soup.find_all('img', class_='profile_photo_img')
    for i in ele:
        print i["data-src"]
        print i["alt"]
```

But it is printing nothing. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: @e4c5 No, it is printing nothing

Comment: @slpcf: Please also share how you are creating the object `soup`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
elements = soup.findAll('img', attrs={'class':'profile_photo_img'})
for element in elements:
    print element['data-src']
    print element['alt']
```

Also make sure that the soup is right parsed from the html by printing it before you are searching for elements